# How do I reshape a NumPy multi dimensional array to another array with the same dimensions, but different shape?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a NumPy multi dimensional array of shape (1,76,76,255). I want to reshape it to another multidimensional array of shape (1,255,76,76). It’s still a 4D array, but I need to change the data indices I guess.

Is there an easy way without using loops?

Comment: Have you looked at `np.transpose`?

Comment: @hpaulj `np.transpose` will give you arr.shape[::-1] not the one OP wants

Comment: @tbhaxor, have you looked at the `np.transpose` docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are looking for is [`np.moveaxis()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html) which lets you move a source axis to its destination.

```
>>> arr = np.random.random((1,76,76,255))
>>> 
>>> arr.shape
(1, 76, 76, 255)
>>> arr2 = np.moveaxis(arr, 3, 1)
>>> arr2.shape
(1, 255, 76, 76)
>>>
```

Please note that these axes are 0-indexed

Comment: `transpose` can do anything `moveaxs` can.  `arr.tranpose(0,3,1,2)`

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks for mentioning @hpaulj